# Install a cert with a private key

Tags: c#

I'm converting part of this batch command to managed code:

```
"%~dp0\makecert" -r -pe -n "CN=CompanyName" -ss my -sr localmachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 "%~dp0\server.cer"
```

This not only creates the cert, but it also installs it.

When the cert is installed it looks like this :

[image]

Now I'm trying to get the private cert installed too when using managed code.

This is what I have so far:

```
/// <summary>
///     Install the root authority certificate
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fileName"></param>
private static void InstallRootAuthority(string fileName)
{
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(fileName));
    var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    store.Add(cert);
    store.Close();
}
```

How can I also add the private key?

Comment: I am pretty sure that your code is valid. Are you 100% sure that the certificate at `fileName` contains a private key? Usually, when a certificate file contains a private key, it is password protected and I don't see you using a password

Comment: Also another Thing I don't quite understand: Your method is named `InstallRootAuthority` but you are Installing it into `StoreName.My`. Usually, root certificates belong into `StoreName.Root`, otherwise client certificates and server certificates will not be verified automatically. Did you do this on purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to pull this off you will need to use a .pfx file (which I believe contains not only the cert but also the private key).

So here is what I did.

1. Generate the cert using MakeCert.exe like this:

> "%~dp0\makecert" -r -pe -n "CN=CompanyName" -ss my -sr localmachine
>   -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 "%~dp0\server.cer" -sv Server.pvk

Notice at the end, that -sv Server.pvk (That's the private key).

2. pvk2pfx.exe -pvk Server.pvk -spc Server.cer -pfx Server.pfx

This prompted me for a password and I selected None. Trying to include a password resulted in bad things happening.

3. Now in your code, adjust like this :

   private static void InstallRootAuthority(string fileName)
                   {
                       var cert = new X509Certificate2(fileName,string.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
                       var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                       store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
                       store.Add(cert);
                       store.Close();
                   }

Excuse formatting, but stackoverflow formatting was broken at time of answering.